# Counting quantities using join and nested queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to count stock quantities from active sales orders, which are stored in xcart_order_details. I also want to only count stock from orders placed within x days which have a status of processed 'P' or queued 'Q', and also if the stock type matches certain locations; C1 stock, C2 stock, and so on.

This used to be relatively simple in our old xcart database;

```
SELECT COUNT(`amount`)
FROM `xcart_order_details`
WHERE `productid` IN (
  SELECT `productid`
  FROM `xcart_products` WHERE `orderid` IN
    (SELECT `orderid`
     FROM `xcart_orders`
     WHERE `date` > ".$date_range."
       AND (`status` = 'P'
            OR `status` = 'Q'))
  AND (LOWER(param01) = 'c1 stock'
       OR LOWER(param01) = 'c2 stock'
       OR LOWER(param01) = 'g stock'
       OR LOWER(param01) = 'stock')
  AND `productid` = ".$safe_prodid.")
```

This query worked. But now our stock locations are stored in another table called xcart_extra_field_values, and must be retrieved where fieldid = 5;

I've tried using a join to get the value field from xcart_extra_field_values where the fieldid = 5, and attempt to do what I'm doing with the query above, but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT COUNT(`a.amount`)
FROM xcart_order_details a,
     xcart_extra_field_values b
WHERE a.productid IN (
  SELECT productid
  FROM xcart_products WHERE orderid IN
    (SELECT orderid
     FROM xcart_orders
     WHERE date > 1409529600
       AND (status = 'P'
            OR status = 'Q'))
  AND (LOWER(b.value) = 'c1 stock'
       OR LOWER(b.value) = 'c2 stock'
       OR LOWER(b.value) = 'g stock'
       OR LOWER(b.value) = 'stock')
  AND (a.productid = b.productid)
  AND (a.productid = 4169)
  AND (b.fieldid = 5)
```

Unfortunately this query does not work, and I know it's a syntax issue, but the error I'm getting is no help whatsoever.

Can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I was getting:

"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 19"

Which in hindsight makes sense, but it was unclear at the time.

Comment: It is strange to see, btw, that you count records that have an amount. If this is on purpose and you don't select any other values from the table, it would be more readable if you excluded NULLs in your WHERE clause (`AND amount IS NOT NULL)`) and count records ( `COUNT(*)`) instead. If amount is never NULL than count records (again `COUNT(*)`) rather than non-null occurences of amount that can never be null anyhow. (And of course if you wanted to count the total amount, you would *SUM* the amounts to get this total.)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the criteria how to join the two tables. Let's assume there is an xcart_order_details_id in table xcart_extra_field_values, then use that.

After all, you don't even have to join. You want results from xcart_order_details for which certain detail value records EXIST:

```
SELECT COUNT(`amount`)
FROM `xcart_order_details`
WHERE `productid` IN 
(
  SELECT `productid`
  FROM `xcart_products` 
  WHERE `orderid` IN
  (
    SELECT `orderid`
    FROM `xcart_orders`
    WHERE `date` > ".$date_range."
    AND `status` IN ('P','Q')
  )
AND `productid` = ".$safe_prodid."
AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM xcart_extra_field_values v
  WHERE v.xcart_order_details_id = xcart_order_details.id
  AND fieldid = 5
  AND LOWER(param01) IN ('c1 stock','c2 stock','g stock','stock')
);
```

BTW: You count how many order detail records have an amount?

Comment: This may be correct, but looks like an entirely different way of doing what I'm doing, and I've now got my query working. I'll take a look at this method, though to see if it's more efficient.

The criteria to join my tables is in my query (a.productid = b.productid)

Comment: Now that you mention it ;-) My query does not exactly what your original query does. Neither does yours by the way. Mine gets you all records in the desired date range and status *and* have a certain stock entry, when it should have the desired date range and status *for* a certain stock entry. Your query gets you records in the desired date range and status when the product happens to have some Record in xcart_extra_field_values for the wanted locations. I'll give you an additional comment on your answer.

Comment: Yeah, I've since corrected my own answer. xcart_extra_field_values will always contain entries for each product. I'm basically counting stock from active customer orders for x days where stock is located in specific warehouse locations.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

```
SELECT COUNT(a.amount)
FROM xcart_order_details a,
     xcart_extra_field_values b
WHERE a.productid IN
    (SELECT productid
     FROM xcart_products
     WHERE orderid IN
         (SELECT orderid
          FROM xcart_orders
          WHERE date > 1409529600
            AND (status = 'P'
                 OR status = 'Q'))
       AND (LOWER(b.value) = 'c1 stock'
            OR LOWER(b.value) = 'c2 stock'
            OR LOWER(b.value) = 'g stock'
            OR LOWER(b.value) = 'stock'))
       AND (a.productid = b.productid)
       AND (a.productid = 4169)
       AND (b.fieldid = 5)
```

Firstly, I was missing a bracket at the end of my query as I was nesting two IN queries, and I needed to remove the Grave accents around `a.amount` within COUNT, which it didn't like. I only noticed the missing bracket when I looked at my queries side by side.

Edit: Moved my join outside of my nested IN clause, as it made no sense to have it nested.

Comment: 1. Make sure you join correctly. xcart_order_details and xcart_extra_field_values won't only be connected by productid, do they? 2. It is strange to do a cross join and then discard joined result records inside an IN clause. It's possible, but not really readable. It doesn't look intended somehow, so a third person might surmise a flaw in the query. 3. You should stay away from error-prone comma-separated join syntax which was substituted in standard SQL by explicit joins (INNER JOIN, CROSS JOIN etc.) more then twenty years ago.

Comment: the extra_field_values table will always contain a match on the productid, so nothing is getting discarded.

The Join doesn't need to be inside the IN clause anyway, I should just be able to take it out by moving the end of my main IN clause to just before I perform my join.

Comment: With "discarded" I mean: You cross join two tables. If each has 1000 rows you get a million result records, but then you discard records from your results. You do so with an IN clause, okay, but within that IN clause you use values from outside (from the records in question) which is very uncommon. It is a trick and it works, but you have to be careful about that and know what you are actually doing. It is not regarded very readable or maintainable.

Comment: I'm not quite following. In my join clause, I'm selecting the result where a.productid = 4169, so my join should only return one result, shouldn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your last edit, where you moved some of your WHERE clause to outside your IN clause. For xcart_extra_field_values there is always just one entry per productid and fieldid? Then you are right. You join xcart_order_details with its product. (Then I only wonder why you join xcart_extra_field_values to xcart_order_details and not to xcart_products.)

Comment: I should also mention every product has only one result where b.fieldid = 5. The xcart_extra_field_values table is just extending x_cart_products table.

Comment: Yes every product has only one result where b.fieldid = 5. The xcart_extra_field_values table is just extending x_cart_products table.

I'm doing the join this way as I have to cross reference active orders from xcart_order_details, and the order date and status from x_cart_orders. I could probably do it in a different order, but the query makes sense to me. :)